# How to assign data from pandas groupby function to a variable?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a question regarding Pandas.
I grouped data by column (Districts)

```
GroupByDistrict = df.groupby(['District'])
```

and then I want to get data

```
print(GroupByDistrict['Price'].agg(['median','mean']))
```

Output of this command shows average prices in different districts.
How can I assign this data to a variable (list or dictionary)?

If I do something like this

```
xx = GroupByDistrict['Price'].agg(['median','mean']) 
print(xx)
```

the output gives object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that as:

```
district_prices = df.groupby('District').agg({'Price': [ 'median', 'mean']}).apply(list).to_dict()

print(district_prices)
```